# Cypress Electron console log format pattern

Tags: logging, electron, cypress

How can I simplify my cypress-electron console output for better readability to NOT contain timestamp and source?

I am starting our cypress tests headless like so:

```js
@SET ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true 
@SET DEBUG=cypress:electron
@SET CYPRESS_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:15002
npx cypress run --spec "cypress/e2e/01_base.cy.js"
```

Output I get:

```js
[18816:0226/074643.800:INFO:CONSOLE(85)] "mylog message 1", source: http://127.0.0.1:15002/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\e2e.js (85)
[18816:0226/074644.607:INFO:CONSOLE(82)] "mylog message 2", source: http://127.0.0.1:15002/editor/webChannel.js (82)
```

Output I would like to get:

```js
mylog message 1
mylog message 2
```

I have found
https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log#transport
and
https://github.com/megahertz/electron-log/blob/feaf2f30a74e4c5c809de992296baf0198a6cd66/docs/transports/format.md

But where would I have the correct context to set
`log.transports.console.format = '{text}';` ?

Ideally there would be an environment variable to set for the format string, but I couldn't find one!

*Edit*: The messages are sent by the client application (running in electron), not from within the cypress tests!

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 4):

One way that seems to work for simple logs is to `console.log()` via the Node process, via a task.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("task", {
        log(message) {
          console.log(message);
          return null;
        }
      })
    },
  },
})
```

My POC test:

```js
it('logging to console', () => {
  console.log('mylog message 1')
  console.log('mylog message 2')
  cy.task('log', 'mylog message 3')
  cy.task('log', 'mylog message 4')
})
```

[image]

---

#### Redirecting logs from the app window

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('https://example.com', {
    onBeforeLoad: (contentWindow => {
      contentWindow.console.log = (msg) => {
        cy.task('log', msg)
      }
    })
  })
})

it('logging to console', () => {
  console.log('mylog message 1')
  console.log('mylog message 2')
  cy.task('log', 'mylog message 3')
  cy.task('log', 'mylog message 4')

  cy.window().then(contentWindow => {
    // any messages sent to the app's console.log() redirected to task log
    contentWindow.console.log('message 5 - from app')
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But isn't it that this way I can only get messages from cypress (tests) to log without decoration and not the ones originating from electron (browser/client)?

Comment: Looking at your code.. how does console.log behave differently, when placed inside cypress test (msg1 and 2 with decorum) and cypress.config.js (msg3 and 4 without decorum)?

Comment: I thank you again for your efforts, but my question is not yet answered! You suggested a solution that works on messages from within the tests, not from within electron/client. Any further ideas?

Comment: Yes, I thought there might be more to it. Not sure what "electron/client" exactly entails, but logs from the app under test are redirected via the app's window.

Comment: Aaah, very good. Unfortunately my "app" (<-thats what i ment by electron/client) sends a lot of messages. Not only during task execution. So when going down that route, I get a lot of exceptions, like "Uncaught CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise. The command that returned the promise was: `cy.get()` The cy command you invoked inside the promise was: `cy.task()`

Comment: or if I try (without understanding why) 'cy.now('task', 'log', msg );'  "Unhandled rejection CypressError: `cy.task()` must only be invoked from the spec file or support file. at http://127.0.0.1:15002/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:135687:72. Just out of curiosity: how can I detect if code is running from within a task, to avoid calling cy.task then?

Answer (score 3):

You can try out the [cypress-terminal-report](https://github.com/archfz/cypress-terminal-report) plugin.

It's got a few options that may suit your requirement. For example to log just console methods (presuming that is what you need), use the following configuration

**cypress/support/e2e.js**

```js
// Options for log collector
const options = {
  // Log console output only
  collectTypes: ["cons:log", "cons:info", "cons:warn", "cons:error"],
};

// Register the log collector
require("cypress-terminal-report/src/installLogsCollector")(options);
```

Internally it does the same trick as shown by @TesterDick to patch the console calls.

Comment: Very neat! Thank you for that link! With a custom output method I can log my undecorated messages into a file, which does the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

My edit of "Aladin Spaz" answer has been rejected. So here is the answer to my question. A custom output function for cypress-terminal-report plugin that allows to output certain messages without decoration:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
        const options = {
            outputRoot: config.projectRoot + '/logs/',
            printLogsToConsole: "never",
            outputTarget: {
              'custom.output': function (allMessages) {
                Object.entries(allMessages).forEach(([spec, tests]) => {
                  let text = `${spec}:\n`
                  Object.entries(tests).forEach(([test, messages]) => {
                    text += `    ${test}\n`
                    messages.forEach(({type, message, severity}) => {
                        if (type.substring(0,4) === "cons") {
                            text += `${message}\n`
                        } else {
                            text += `    ${type} (${severity}): ${message}\n`;
                        }
                    })
                  })
                  this.writeSpecChunk(spec, text);
                });
              }
            },
        };
        require('cypress-terminal-report/src/installLogsPrinter')(on, options);
    },
  },
});
```